# Methods to feed multiple images of same object to neural network for object detection

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, image-recognition

I am thinking about a toy project that would use a neural network for object recognition. Some of my objects are quite similar when viewed from one specific angle but easily distinguishable when viewed from a different angle. Thus my question:

What are methods to feed multiple images of the same object into a network? Or which network architectures exist that can take advantage of multiple images taken at different angles?

I have a good understanding of machine learning techniques but only basic understanding of neural networks. So what I am looking for here is both names of methods, techniques and other jargon that would be relevant for a google search as well as links to specific papers or articles that could be of interest.

Comment: what do you mean by different angle? is it like rotating image by 90, 180.. degrees shows you different object?

Comment: @Pramod: No. Two different objects looks the same when viewed from one given angle. If you rotate them both by 90deg on a given axis, only then are they distinguishable. Thus, I need images from different angles to be able to classify properly.

Comment: So your are talking about data augmentation. Data augmentation will increase the data size and the CNNs will actually become robust by feeding images from different angles. Any network will improve by doing this. See this question https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5224/how-to-prepare-augment-images-for-neural-network

Comment: @Pramod: Thanks for the link but I am not talking about data augmentation here. I need the network to know that I am feeding it two images from different angles of the same object. By just throwing in these two images as two separate samples I would miss important information. Thomas' answer below is what I was after.

Comment: @Toby what approach did you end up choosing? I'm currently doing a similar problem and was wondering what you ended up doing.

Comment: I ended up using several inputs (one input per camera) and using a Keras merge layer on them. My objects don't always show the same side to the same camera, they can be arbitrarily rotated. In other words, I wanted the network to treat the following two cases as equal: 'cam 1 shows a, cam 2 shows b' and 'cam 1 shows b, cam 2 shows a). I am not completely sure about this though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common ones using multidimensional data use either multidimensional convolutions (https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv3d),  recurrent networks (http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/rnn.html) or multiple inputs, which is kinda similar to multidimensional convolutions.

Recurrent Networks handle sequences of data and the stacks of images can be seen a sequence. In contrast the multidimensional convolutions mostly exploit nearby data. Therefore it is important that the same space is highly correlated across your image stack. If this is not the case, you might want to consider using multiple inputs into your neural network.